# How to fix a Primefaces file download <p:fileDownload> inside a commandButton that works only on the second time?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, download

I´m developing a new funcionality and I need it to download a CSV file generated from a database query. I´m using Primefaces 3.5 with JSF 2.1 and JBoss 6.1. The IDE is Eclipse Oxygen.

Mainly, the user can download employee files related to some month/year date. But, when I click on the download button, it doesn´t work at the first time. Oddly, when the button is clicked again, it works fine!

The funcionality has two screens:

First: in this screen there is one form, in which the user can access the second screen through two buttons. 
Any of the buttons opens the second screen (there are two buttons due to some future features, so don´t mind about it right now). 
The buttons redirect the flow using a string return of the method defined on the action tag.

In the second screen the user is able to choose a date in the selectOneMenu box and click over the button. When the user does so, the csv file is generated.

But, as said before, at the first time clicked, the server is contacted (message is shown in the browser bar), but no file is downloaded. At the second time the user clicks the button, the file is downloaded.

No exception is thrown.

I´ve already tried to change the code using h: tags instead of p:, put the button outside the panelGrid and searched the internet with no success.

Some code changes made the file to be generated during the second screen loading, prior to download button click. But it isn´t desirable.

First screen code: arquivoDiariasDFI.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body >

<ui:composition template="/layout/common.xhtml">

        <ui:param name="mbean" value="#{arquivoDiariasDFIManagedBean}" />
        <ui:param name="entity" value="Arquivos de Diarias - DFI" />

    <ui:define name="content">

        <h:form id="tela2" acceptcharset="ISO-8859-1">
            <h:outputScript library="javascript" name="locale-primefaces.js" />
            <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="false" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" globalOnly="false"  />

            <div class="lblFuncionalidade">#{entity}</div>

            <div>       
                    <p></p>
                    <p:panelGrid border="1" width="100%"  > 
                        <p:row style="border:0px; width:100%" columns="3"  >
                            <p:column style="border:0px; font-weight:bold; width:10%" > Mes Base:  </p:column>
                            <p:column style="border:0px; font-weight:bold; width:50%">
                                    <p:selectOneMenu id="smMesBase" filter="true" value="#{mbean.arquivoDiariasDFI.dataBase}" 
                                                 required="true" requiredMessage="Campo Obrigatorio: Mes Base" disabled="#{mbean.desabDataBase}"  >
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione o mes base"  />
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{mbean.datasBases}" var="dtBase" itemValue="#{dtBase}" 
                                                   itemLabel="#{dtBase}" >
                                    </f:selectItems>
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column style="border:0px;" >
                                        <h:commandButton value="Gerar arquivo de integrantes" id="botaoIntegrantes"
                                            action="#{mbean.botaoArquivoFuncionarios()}" 
                                             onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);" > 
                                            <p:fileDownload value="#{mbean.arquivo}"/> 
                                        </h:commandButton>
                            </p:column>


                        </p:row>
                    </p:panelGrid>

                    <p></p>

            <!--  -->           
            </div>
            <p:ajaxStatus onstart="statusDialog.show();" oncomplete="statusDialog.hide();" />

            <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog" showHeader="false"
                      draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="false">
                <p:graphicImage value="../imagens/ajax-loader.gif" />
            </p:dialog>

        </h:form>



</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Second screen code arquivoDiariasDFI_detalhe.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body >

<ui:composition template="/layout/common.xhtml">

        <ui:param name="mbean" value="#{arquivoDiariasDFIManagedBean}" />
        <ui:param name="entity" value="Arquivos de Diarias - DFI" />

    <ui:define name="content">

        <h:form id="tela2" acceptcharset="ISO-8859-1">
            <h:outputScript library="javascript" name="locale-primefaces.js" />
            <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="false" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" globalOnly="false"  />

            <div class="lblFuncionalidade">#{entity}</div>

            <div>       
                    <p></p>
                    <p:panelGrid border="1" width="100%"  > 
                        <p:row style="border:0px; width:100%" columns="3"  >
                            <p:column style="border:0px; font-weight:bold; width:10%" > Mes Base:  </p:column>
                            <p:column style="border:0px; font-weight:bold; width:50%">
                                    <p:selectOneMenu id="smMesBase" filter="true" value="#{mbean.arquivoDiariasDFI.dataBase}" 
                                                 required="true" requiredMessage="Campo Obrigatorio: Mes Base" disabled="#{mbean.desabDataBase}"  >
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione o mes base"  />
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{mbean.datasBases}" var="dtBase" itemValue="#{dtBase}" 
                                                   itemLabel="#{dtBase}" >
                                    </f:selectItems>
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column style="border:0px;" >
                                        <h:commandButton value="Gerar arquivo de integrantes" id="botaoIntegrantes"
                                            action="#{mbean.botaoArquivoFuncionarios()}" 
                                             onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);" > 
                                            <p:fileDownload value="#{mbean.arquivo}"/> 
                                        </h:commandButton>
                            </p:column>


                        </p:row>
                    </p:panelGrid>

                    <p></p>

            <!--  -->           
            </div>
            <p:ajaxStatus onstart="statusDialog.show();" oncomplete="statusDialog.hide();" />

            <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog" showHeader="false"
                      draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="false">
                <p:graphicImage value="../imagens/ajax-loader.gif" />
            </p:dialog>

        </h:form>



</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Managed bean (suppressed code).

```
package mppr.srh.dominio.bean;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;

import org.primefaces.model.DefaultStreamedContent;
import org.primefaces.model.StreamedContent;

import mppr.srh.manager.ArquivoDiariasDFIManagerLocal;
import mppr.srh.manager.FuncionarioManagerLocal;
import mppr.srh.model.ArquivoDiariasDFI;
import mppr.srh.model.Funcionario;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped 
public class ArquivoDiariasDFIManagedBean  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String status = "tela1";     //Controle de tela
    private Boolean desabDataBase = false; //Controle de botão Mes Base

    private List < Funcionario > funcionarios;

    @EJB
    FuncionarioManagerLocal funcionarioManagerLocal;

    @EJB
    private ArquivoDiariasDFIManagerLocal svc; 

    private List < ArquivoDiariasDFI >  listArquivoDiariasDFI;
    private ArquivoDiariasDFI arquivoDiariasDFI;
    private List < String > datasBases;

    private StreamedContent arquivo;
    String nomeArq;



    //Métodos "padrão"
    @PostConstruct
    public void construct(){
        this.setStatus("tela1");
        listArquivoDiariasDFI = svc.retornaTodasAsDiarias();
    }

    public List<String> getDatasBases() {
        return datasBases;
    }

    public void setDatasBases(List<String> datasBases) {
        this.datasBases = datasBases;
    }

    public String getNomeArq() {
        return nomeArq;
    }

    public void setNomeArq(String nomeArq) {
        this.nomeArq = nomeArq;
    }

    public Boolean getDesabDataBase() {
        return desabDataBase;
    }

    public void setDesabDataBase(Boolean desabDataBase) {
        this.desabDataBase = desabDataBase;
    }

    public List<ArquivoDiariasDFI> getListArquivoDiariasDFI() {
        return listArquivoDiariasDFI;
    }



    public void setListArquivoDiariasDFI(List<ArquivoDiariasDFI> listArquivoDiariasDFI) {
        this.listArquivoDiariasDFI = listArquivoDiariasDFI;
    }



    public ArquivoDiariasDFI getArquivoDiariasDFI() {
        return arquivoDiariasDFI;
    }



    public void setArquivoDiariasDFI(ArquivoDiariasDFI arquivoDiariasDFI) {
        this.arquivoDiariasDFI = arquivoDiariasDFI;
    }



    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public List<Funcionario> getFuncionarios() {
        return funcionarios;
    }

    public void setFuncionarios(List<Funcionario> funcionarios) {
        this.funcionarios = funcionarios;
    }

    public void setArquivo(StreamedContent arquivo) {
        this.arquivo = arquivo;
    }

    public StreamedContent getArquivo() throws IOException {

        return arquivo;

    }

    public void botaoArquivoFuncionarios() throws IOException {

        //Abre classes de escrita em arquivo
        this.nomeArq = "ListaFuncionarios" + this.arquivoDiariasDFI.getDataBase().replace("/","") + ".csv";

        File f = this.gerarArquivoFuncionarios();
        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream (f);

        arquivo = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "", nomeArq);


    }

    public File gerarArquivoFuncionarios() throws IOException { 

        File f = new File(this.nomeArq);

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        PrintStream ps = null;

        try {

            fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            ps = new PrintStream(fos);

            //Carrega todos os funcionários
            this.setFuncionarios(funcionarioManagerLocal.getFuncionarioAnual(1)); //Pega funcionarios com data_fim ate um ano atras

            ps.println("CPF, NOME, CARGO");

            for (Funcionario func : funcionarios) {

                ps.println(String.format("%s, %s, %s", func.getNoCpf(), func.getNmFuncionario(), func.getCargo().getDsCargo()  ));


            }
            ps.flush();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            try {

                if (fos != null) {
                    fos.close();
                }
                if (ps != null ) {
                    ps.close();
                }

                return f;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        return f;

    }


    //
    public String abrirTelaDeEnvio() {

        this.setDatasBases(this.carregaDatasBases());
        //Foi selecionado um registro (data base preenchida)
        if (arquivoDiariasDFI != null) {

            this.setStatus("tela2_alteracao");
            this.desabDataBase = true;

            //carrega arquivo de acordo com processamento. 


        } else {
            this.setStatus("tela2_novo");
            this.desabDataBase = false;
            arquivoDiariasDFI = new ArquivoDiariasDFI();
            arquivoDiariasDFI.setSituacao(1);
            this.setDatasBases(this.carregaDatasBases());
        }

        return "arquivoDiariasDFI_detalhe.xhtml"; //retorno para navegação.

    }   

    //Carrega lista de Meses Bases: de hoje até 1 ano atrás. 
    //Já retorna convertida para String.
    public List < String > carregaDatasBases() {

        ArrayList < String > retorno = new ArrayList<String>();

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        c.setTime( new Date());

        Date data = c.getTime();

        retorno.add(formataMesBase(data));

        int incremento = 1;
        while (incremento <= 12) {

            c.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1 );
            data = c.getTime();
            retorno.add( formataMesBase(data) );

            incremento ++;
        }

        return retorno;

    }

    public String formataMesBase(Date pData) {

        SimpleDateFormat sDF = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy");

        String data = sDF.format(pData);

        return data;

    }

    // CONVERTERS
    // CONVERSOR PERSONALIZADO PARA SELECTIONBOX DE DATA BASE
    public Converter getdataBaseConverter(){ 
         return dataBaseConverter;
    }

    private Converter dataBaseConverter = new Converter() {

        @Override
        public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent comp, String pValue) {

            if (pValue == null || pValue.equals("") || pValue.isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            } else {

                return Integer.parseInt(pValue); 
            }

        }


        @Override
        public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent comp, Object pDataBase) {

            if(pDataBase == null || pDataBase.equals("")) {
                return null;
            } else {

                return String.valueOf(pDataBase);

            }

        }

    }; //fim do converter



}
```

I expect the file download to work properly when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

The file must be generated and returned by its get method inside de ManagedBean. If the file generation is outside the get method, the FileDownload doesn´t work. (At least in this Primefaces version).